# MongoDB : A Service Specific error occurred :100

Tags: mongodb

I have just installed "mongodb" on Windows, while starting it, the following error appears

> A Service Specific error occurred :100

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What command you are running? Also which OS are you using?

Comment: OS: Windows 7
Command: `net start MongoDB`

Comment: Have you created the required directories?

Comment: Do you mean `\data\db` and `\log` in mongodb installation directory?

Comment: please show us command line how you created the service and config file dump

Comment: Command : `> mongod  --directoryperdb --dbpath  C:\mongodb\data\db  --logpath C:\mongodb\log\mongodb.log  --logappend --rest --install`

Comment: Not sure what happened but its working now :)

Comment: This happened to me because the service was already running. Check that it is stopped using net stop MongoDB and then start it again either from services or from the cmd (running as administrator) : net start MongoDB

Answer (score 15):

The reason for this error message is that you have another process already established.
In my case it was the mongod.exe file I had opened in CMD, when I closed it and restarted the net start MongoDB command, it connected successfully.
BTW i am using Windows 10 current build as of July 2017 with MongoDB 3.4

Comment: This answer helped me after a google search of the error. Thank you! I'm using 3.4 on Windows 10 as well.

Comment: +1. I also had another `mongod.exe` process established in CMD in administrator mode. Once I closed it and attempted another `net start MongoDB`, it worked and connected successfully.

Answer (score 7):

Please try running the below commands as Administrator in the comment prompt.

1. `mongod --repair`
2. `mongod --remove`

then like @Yahya did, specify the log path,

3. `mongod --install --logpath C:\data\db\log\mongo.log`
4. `net start mongodb`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

For me, somehow directories I have specified for db and log config file were not auto created.

```
dbpath=\data\db

logpath=\data\log\mongo.log
```

so I created them manually then ran the command again and service started.

I am using v3.4.9 om Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Check your Mongo log in your /data/log folder (which you should have created during install), there might be a solution in there.

I had this issue, I checked the System Event Log which gave me the following:

```
The MongoDB service terminated with the following service-specific error: Cannot create another system semaphore.
```

When I checked the log I found this:

```
Unable to create/open lock file: c:\data\db\mongod.lock The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.. Is a mongod instance already running?
```

Turns out I'd started the process manually in another command window so it couldn't start it again. You may have a different issue but the log should tell you what is going on!

Answer (score 2):

For example mongoDB version 3.6 is installed, and the installing path of MongoDB is "D:\Program Files\MongoDB".

Create folder `D:\mongodb\logs`, then create file `mongodb.log` inside this folder.

Run cmd.exe as **administrator**,

```
D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>taskkill /F /IM mongod.exe
D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod.exe --logpath D:\mongodb\logs\mongodb.log --logappend --dbpath D:\mongodb\data --directoryperdb --serviceName MongoDB --remove
D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod --logpath "D:\mongodb\logs\mongodb.log" --logappend --dbpath "D:\mongodb\data" --directoryperdb --serviceName "MongoDB" --serviceDisplayName "MongoDB" --install
```

Remove these two files `mongod.lock` and `storage.bson` under the folder "D:\mongodb\data".

Then type `net start MongoDB` in the cmd using administrator, the issue will be gone.

Comment: In version 4, just removing the two files worked for me!

Comment: @user1574598
Cool~

Comment: Yeah it was complaining about a flag I had used previously that wasn't part of the config file when I tried to run the service `--directoryperdb` so it looked as though `--remove` was not fully working.  Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

execute the command

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe"
```

and check which error is displayed

Running **mongod.exe** through a service does not display the error messages. In my case, i didnt created the directory **/data/db**, which i specified in my configuration file. My Configuration file is based on the docs [create-a-configuration-file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#create-a-configuration-file)

The error was only displayed after **executing the command directly**

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to that service is already started. If you are not done it, then please check your database path and log path in the mongodb.cfg (The file which stores mongodb configuration) file.

Eg:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: H:\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: H:\data\db
processManagement:
   windowsService:
      serviceName: "MongoDB"
      displayName: "Mongo DB"
      description: "mongod service"
```

If you doesn't have it then please create one.

Also you can use the following step to fix this issue,

please run the follow as administrator.

```
sc.exe qc MongoDB
```

If there are no logs, then MongoDB likely cannot open the log file due to a permission issue.

Also, try installing the service as

```
D:\servers\db\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath=D:\servers\db\mongodb\data --logpath=D:\servers\db\mongodb\log\mongo.log --logappend --install
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue
In the config one of the path was

```
C:\MongoDB\data\db
```

But nor the data or db folder existed
I expected them to be generated automatically.